# Can We Export Our Jiras from Dashbord to an Excel Sheet?

Tags: jira, jira-plugin, jira-rest-java-api, jira-mobile-connect

Currently I'm using Jira 5.2 version. I would like to import the contents of my dashboard to an excel for an internal audit. Is it possible?  Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found the solution for it.

Please refer the below link for more details.

[Exporting Jira Details to Excel](https://confluence.atlassian.com/display/JIRA/Exporting+Search+Results+to+Microsoft+Excel)

Answer (score 0):

If you wanted to export a list of issues from Issue Navigator, then you can use the built-in [Export to Excel](https://confluence.atlassian.com/display/JIRA/Exporting+Search+Results+to+Microsoft+Excel) feature as a trivial option. If you need more power, then use the [Better Excel Plugin](https://marketplace.atlassian.com/plugins/com.midori.jira.plugin.betterexcel), which is Excel-export-on-steroids :-) It takes a different approach for producing Excel spreadsheets, and it comes with [a lot of advantages](http://www.midori-global.com/products/jira-better-excel-plugin#comparison).

None of these will export the dashboards themselves though. XLSX would not be a very good choice for output format for dashboards, as a dashboard isn't a typical cells-in-a-sheet structure. You may have rich formatted texts, various visualizations, that cannot be easily enforced and transformed into cells.

You can use the [PDF View Plugin](https://marketplace.atlassian.com/plugins/com.midori.jira.plugin.pdfview) to export dashboards to PDF documents instead.

[image]

*Disclaimer: I'm a programmer working on this software.*

Answer (score 0):

With add-on **JExcel**, you can easily import/export JIRA data from/to Excel.

It is also possible to use **Ctrl C + Ctrl V** for importing and exporting.

It totally feels like an Excel in JIRA. And Its completely **free**!

You can download it from the Marketplace: https://marketplace.atlassian.com/plugins/com.moresimp.jexcel